# Visual Studio 2010 runs awful - can't find solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2010 Professional - I'm working on a project at work, and everything in VS runs slow (maybe except IntelliSense). I know that start-up times usually are quite bad, and I can live with that.

But building a medium sized solution (7 projects, a few hundred files) takes from 3 to even 10 minutes... After building the solution VS says that it's ready, but I have to wait for the localhost to respond up to 5 minutes... That's up to 15 minutes in total!
To keep things short:

- after turning on everything I still have at least 1Gb of free RAM (4 total) and only 20-25% of processor usage
- I have uninstalled every plugin
- The project builds and works fine on my teammate's computer
- The project works and builds even better when I work on a server using my computer and a virtual desktop
- My computer works just fine
- I have just finished the painful re-installation of VS (after removing VS cleaning it's leftovers - or so I think)

EDIT: After cleaning up my solution my build times are blazing fast! :) Plus, I was able to find out that I have some kind of problem with my processor, which didn't show up in the process manager until now... Anyway, I think my problem has been solved somehow...
THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you have your project stored on the network? that can cause delays. At best, keep all your visual studio and project files local.

Comment: @ChristianSauer No, everything is local :(

Comment: will it go faster if you just build the solution with MSBuild? (Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt and enter `msbuild` to start it)

Comment: What's the machine specs? If it's a quad-core, 20-25% could mean that a core is fully occupied, which is quite abnormal.

Comment: Sounds like your HDD is performing very bad. You could try to go through your project references and set the 'Copy Local' option to false on those where you don't need it. It should reduce the I/O traffic. It's not guaranteed to build faster, but worth a shot.

Comment: I would look into what Resource Monitor claims are consuming your resources, specifically disk queue lengths and what other processes are using your harddrive.

Comment: @SimonSvensson http://i48.tinypic.com/r0o1fo.png here is a screenshot

Comment: @JulienLebosquain I'm running on a I3

Comment: @SzymonSajdak, something is off if you're writing 7.5mb/s when idle. Sort on the write/combined speed in the lower pane to see which files are written to, and determine which program/service causes it.

Comment: @SzymonSajdak, try to disable for a while `Windows Defender ` (`MsMpEng.exe` process). Yo can use Process Lasso Free Edition software to permament process kill (`MsMpEng.exe` will restart after simple, task manager process kill). Try to build your solution and check performance gain. Remember that you will loose your virus protection after `MsMpEng.exe` permament disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fact that Visual Studio 2010 (devenv.exe process), eats a los of memory.

Sometimes when I want to fast develop a little project or just make a fast script
I use Visual Studio 2008 because resouce consumption with previous version is evident.

I recommend you to unistall all the visual studio 2010 extensions if you have any and
make a new Solution for your project collections if the solution you are currently using
was created long time ago.

You can try also VS2012. It has become better talking about resource consumption

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change my IDE, because I'm working in a team and we both need to sync (we use git)... Plus reinstalling would mean another day of and deadlines are coming... But I will try to create a new solution :)

Comment: At my enterprise you use huge solutions with more than 20 projects between assemblies and websites. We use to clear the solution one a month

Answer (score 2):

Try to run VS in safe mode

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /SafeMode

This switch prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, thus ensuring stable execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual Studio Memory Wrapper by Jetbrains](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/OutOfMemoryException+Fix). It helped me with my Visual Studio 2010 performance a lot, but it may not work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping all instances of the ASP.NET development server between debugs. My workstation seems to have a hard limit of 20 instances on different ports. As I type this, I have 5 rogue instances running who knows what. I manually close them, and I have warp capability again.

Comment: I will try to do that... Do you think it will help if I use only the same port all the time?

Comment: Visual Studio should automatically use the same port all the time for a single project. But yes, using the same port all the time will mean that only one instance of the ASP.NET development server is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything and your CPU is at 20-25% usage, then there's something wrong with your PC. A modern PC doing nothing but running Windows should use 3-4%.

Comment: Maybe I was a little unclear - the usage is 25% when I have the instances of VS running, one is still building + all the other things running in the background